# RxJava: Create items in list and return new list

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-kotlin

Rx noobie here: any idea on how to achieve this?:

I have a list of items from the UI and would like to POST them to the server. I need the list of POSTed items back from the server (to use the server-issued IDs, timestamps etc).

Pardon my long examples but here's the code I'm struggle to make work:

```
/**
 * create each item (POST) in the list and return the list
 * of newly created ones
 */
fun postItems(items: List<Item>): Maybe<List<Item>> {
    // loop through all items, making a network call for each and return the
    // list of POSTed items

    // attempt 1
    // Failed type inference. Expected type mismatch:
    // Expected: Maybe<List<Item>>
    // Found: List<Maybe<Item>>
    return items.map {
        postItem(it)
    }

    // attempt 2: 'extract' each item in resulting observable and
    // shove it back to original list
    return Maybe.just(items.map {
        postItem(it!!)
                // 'extract' item from observable
                .flatMap {
                    // error: Type mismatch.
                    // Required ((Item) -> MaybeSource<out (???...???)>!)!
                    // Found (Item) -> Item
                    it
                }
    })

    // attempt 3: convert a Maybe to Flowable to collect all items from post
    // and emit them as a single list
    // Type mismatch. Required:(((Mutable)List<Item!>) -> SingleSource<out (???...???)>!)!
    // Found: ((Mutable)List<Item!>) -> (Mutable)List<Item!>
    return items.forEach {
        postItem(it!!).toFlowable().toList().flatMap { it }
    }

    // attempt 4: modify attempt 3 with concatMap:
    // Type mismatch. Required:((List<Item!>) -> MaybeSource<out (???...???)>!)!
    // Found: (List<Item!>) -> List<Maybe<Item>>
    return Maybe.just(items)
            // wait for each observable to finish all the work 
            // until the next one is processed
            .concatMap({
                it.map { addItem(it!!) }
            }).toFlowable()
            .toList().toMaybe()

    // attempt 6: blocking call on each API request.
    // results in android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    return Maybe.just(places.map {
        addPlace(it!!).blockingGet()
    })
}

fun postItem(item: Item): Maybe<Item> {
    return networkService.post(item) // async call to API, returns Maybe<Item>
}
```

**UPDATE**

I have tried the approach suggested by @AlexeySoshin below but still have some points of confusion:

I have tried the second, shorter approach but the retrofit call doesn't go thru for some reason :(, i.e the network service endpoints aren't hit). It's slightly modified because I couldn't get rx-kotlin wrapper to work, but I imagine it's roughly equivalent to this:

```
fun addItems(items: List<Item?>): Flowable<Maybe<Item>> {
    return Flowable.fromIterable(items).map {
        // tried items.toFlowable().map but got 'Unresolved reference toFlowable
        // even after adding rx-kotlin to project via gradle
        return@map postItem(it)
    }
}
```

My network service works successfully for a single Item with this code:

```
// works as expected
fun postOneItem(item: Item): Maybe<Item> {
    return postItem(item)
}

// also works
fun postOneItemFlowable(item: Item): Flowable<Item> {
    return postItem(item).toFlowable()
}


// this variant didn't work
fun postOneItemFlowable(item: Item): Flowable<Maybe<Item>> {
    return Flowable.just(postItem(item))
}
```

How to make `Flowable<Maybe<Item>>` calls go thru successfully? (or `Flowable<List<Item>>`, which would be closer to what I need eventually)

Finally, how to obtain the actual output list from a
    `Flowable<Maybe<Item>>`? It would help to see how the `.subscribe()`
    block might look like to 'extract' that final list. Here is how my current subscribe code looks like:

```
...
private fun createItem(item: Item) {
    disposables.add(
            addItemUseCase.postOneItem(item)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe({
                        Timber.d("one item posted: $it")
                    }, { /* error handler *//})
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
fun postItems(items: List<Item>): Maybe<List<Item>> {
    return items.toFlowable().map {
        postItem(it).blockingGet()
    }.toList().toMaybe()
}
```

But I'm not sure that's what you actually mean, since your `Maybe` is not a `Maybe`, actually.

Changing the signature like this will make much more sense:

```
fun postItems(items: List<Item>): Flowable<Maybe<Item>> {
    return items.toFlowable().map {
        postItem(it)
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks promising, but how come you have a `List` being converted to a `Flowable` with `items.toFlowable()...`? I thought such methods are only available on an Observable.

Comment: He's probably using `rx-kotlin` (you tagged your question with `rx-kotlin` yourself). `toFlowable()` is an extension function that calls `Flowable.fromIterable()`

Comment: It's RxKotlin, and you can add it with `compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.3.0'`

Comment: @AlexeySoshin I have updated the post to add more info about my experience trying your answer. I appreciate your patience :)

Comment: I cannot run your code, but having `return@map` seems wrong. Usually `return@` is a quick return, like `break` sort of thing. I suggest that you try it with one call to server, and then improve it to work with `map()` of calls.